# Correct way of handling edges of a matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

Supposed we have to write a simple program that transforms a matrix. Each element should be the sum of its neighbor-elements.

What's the "correct" (i.e. most common, has best readability, most effective) way to do this, considering the edges of a matrix?

Two obvious obvious ways of achieving this that I can think of:

1. Handle corners first (4 separate lines), use 4 loops to do the remaining edges, then use the standard loop for the rest
2. Use one loop for the whole matrix with `if`'s to check if we're in the middle or it's an edge-case.

The first one is faster (I guess), but it kinda looks off to me to have 4 lines plus 5 loops for this.

Is there a more elegant way? I tagged this as C++ because I'm coding in C++ currently and I have the feeling that the ternary operator `?:` is gonna come in handy to write a cute solution.

Bonus points if your solution can be tweaked for a more complex rule (not just looking one up/right/left/down cell, but if you're doing a certain kind of recursion). Not sure if it would change things much, though.

Comment: "Each element should be the sum of its neighbor-elements."  For a matrix with more than 2 elements, how could the entries be anything other than all zeroes? Can you give an example?

Comment: encapsulate the summing of edges into functions and it'll look less weird. Really, if it works, it works. Elegance is not always preferred

Comment: @Matt Sorry, I meant to transform the matrix. Element should *become* the sum of neighbor elements. We're creating a new matrix where we exchange each element with sum of its neighbors. It's just a random example, the point of the question is looking at neighbor cells and handling edges which are an exception.

Comment: It seems you are talking about a problem simmilar to [image convolution](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2013/02/calculating-convolution-of-image-with-c_2.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One elegant way of going about it, is to use a larger matrix. If your matrix has NxM elements, make a temporary (N+2)x(M+2) matrix, fill it with zeros and then copy your values like so:

temp(i+1,j+1) <- original(i,j)

Now you actually have your original matrix with zeroed-out edges around it. You can now safely calculate the sum of all neighbors of all the non-edge cells in the temporary matrix. The result will be the matrix you were originally looking for.

Note - this will be less efficient than the straight-forward five-loop-solution you proposed.

Comment: This is especially effective if you can do a series of calculations with the extended matrix.